# Bash: I have 2 country-level datasets in .csv format & would like to filter them for common elements & plot the result

Tags: bash, statistics

I took two data-sets about a country from wikipedia, pasted them into LibreOffice calc & saved them as .csv files. e.g:

**First .csv File:**

```
"Algeria", 76
"Angola", 100
...
"United Arab Emirates", 27
```

**Second .csv File:**

```
"Algeria", .67
"Argentina", .45
...
"Zimbabwe", .57
```

I want to filter the lists for countries with datapoints in both .csv files (assume no duplicates or alternate spellings), match up the two datapoints (e.g. 76, .67 for Algeria) and output some rudimentary scatterplot, to get a quick visual idea of their relationship.

I tried lots of different ways to parse the files & some of them almost worked but I kept getting tripped up by not knowing enough about awk, grep, bash pipes, gnuplot and the like.

I'm sure it'd be easier/better done in Python or Perl or somesuch and I ended up using the "lookup" function in LibreOffice Calc, but having started I'd like to know how it could be done in bash. Ideally, the data-gathering would be automated by parsing the html but sometimes you get these data-sets in pdf tables and so on.

Any class of pointer appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the `join` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a quick and dirty perl one liner script that should output as you need, I guess. I only spend 3 or 5 minutes.

```
$ perl -e 'while(<>){my @dt = split(/,/);chomp $dt[1]; my $tmp=`fgrep $dt[0] two.csv`; my @rs = split(/,/,$tmp);chomp $rs[1]; print $dt[0],$dt[1],$rs[1],"\n" }' one.csv
```

Output :

```
"Algeria" 76 .67
"Angola" 100
"United Arab Emirates" 27
```

I do not treat errors so if one country do not exist on second.csv file they will appear only with this information, and the same way if a country exists only on second.csv I will no get this either.

With this output you should be able to use gnuplot to do what o wanna. Or you could open this file on Excel or OpenOffice Calc.

I hope this help.